# Cloudwatch Alarm- Slack integration : typescript code to create an alarm and publish to SNS using cloud watch metic name for a particular Rest API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, slack, cloudwatch-alarms

I have a requirement to create cloudwatch alarm and integrate it with Slack for one of my Rest API for my application *(there are multiple endpoints in my application ex : /api1 , /api2 , /api3 etc.. and I want to setup cloudwatch alarm only for /api1)*

I tried to do it using below syntax in typescript,

```
const http5xx = applicationTargetGroup.metric("http_server_requests_seconds_sum",{
.....
})
```

But in this way I will be getting combined data for all Rest APIs. Is there a way to get it for a particular endpoint? (say /api only). I am not able to find any parameter under  applicationTargetGroup.metric to mention url etc.